# ConcurrentQueue Not Always Dequeueing what was Successfully Enqueued

Tags: c#, service, queue

I have a Windows service which has been running in my production environment for years.

The service has several ConcurrentQueue instances. One of these queues (queue "A") receives Enqueues from three different "producers", each one within a different thread. The total Enqueue rate for queue "A" is only about 200 per second.

A fourth thread does the Dequeuing.

I’ve made some seemingly unrelated code changes, and am perplexed by what I'm now observing: Queue "A" only correctly processes traffic from two of the three producers.
While debugging, I stopped the Enqueues from the two "working" producers, and observed the following with the "problem producer":

1. When I step through the Enqueue statement, everything looks fine: That is, the Queue.Count correctly increments, Queue.IsEmpty == false, and my data is correctly residing in a queue element.
2. However, when the fourth thread calls TryDequeue on the same queue, nothing is found. Also, Queue.IsEmpty == true, and Queue.Count == 0.
3. Repeated Enqueues cause the Queue.Count to keep increasing and my new items accumulating, as shown by the debugger.

Has anyone ever encountered this type of behavior?
Thanks in advance,
Dave

Here is the code. The problem areas are marked ***.

```
private struct tLogQueueElment{
    public DateTime utcTimeStamp;
    public string Data;
    public teFileType eFileType;
    public teShowfileOption eShowfileOption;
}
private ConcurrentQueue<tLogQueueElment> oLogQueue;
private ConcurrentQueue<tLogQueueElment>[] oLogQueues; //for the call channels
private ConcurrentQueue<TokenRing.Log.tLogQueueItem> rTokenRingLogQueue;

public void Enqueue_FromExec_NoTimeStamp(string Data)
{
    tLogQueueElment QueueElment;
    QueueElment.utcTimeStamp = NULL_DATETIME;
    QueueElment.Data = Data;
    QueueElment.eFileType = teFileType.NORMAL;
    QueueElment.eShowfileOption = teShowfileOption.WRITE_TO_IT;
    oLogQueue.Enqueue(QueueElment);
}
public void Enqueue_FromExec_NoTimeStamp(string Data, teFileType eFileType)
{
    tLogQueueElment QueueElment;
    QueueElment.utcTimeStamp = NULL_DATETIME;
    QueueElment.Data = Data;
    QueueElment.eFileType = eFileType;
    QueueElment.eShowfileOption = teShowfileOption.WRITE_TO_IT;
    oLogQueue.Enqueue(QueueElment);
}
public void Enqueue_FromSerializerThread(string Data, teFileType eFileType)
{
    //*** This is the one that doesn’t get dequeued. The two above do get dequeued.
    tLogQueueElment QueueElment;
    QueueElment.utcTimeStamp = DateTime.UtcNow;
    QueueElment.Data = Data;
    QueueElment.eFileType = eFileType;
    QueueElment.eShowfileOption = teShowfileOption.WRITE_TO_IT;
    oLogQueue.Enqueue(QueueElment);
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
public void EnqueueFromModemThread_NoTimeStamp(int Index, string Data)
{
    //Index is the zero-based modem index 
    tLogQueueElment QueueElment;
    QueueElment.utcTimeStamp = NULL_DATETIME;
    QueueElment.Data = Data;
    QueueElment.eFileType = teFileType.NORMAL;
    QueueElment.eShowfileOption = teShowfileOption.WRITE_TO_IT;
    oLogQueues[Index].Enqueue(QueueElment);
}
public void EnqueueFromModemThread(int Index, string Data)
{
    //Index is the zero-based modem index 
    EnqueueFromModemThread(Index, Data, teFileType.NORMAL);
}
public void EnqueueFromModemThread(int Index, string Data, teFileType eFileType)
{
    //Index is the zero-based modem index 
    tLogQueueElment QueueElment;
    QueueElment.utcTimeStamp = DateTime.UtcNow;
    QueueElment.Data = Data;
    QueueElment.eFileType = eFileType;
    QueueElment.eShowfileOption = teShowfileOption.WRITE_TO_IT;
    oLogQueues[Index].Enqueue(QueueElment);
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
private void ThreadRoutine()
{
    tLogQueueElment QueueElment; 
    TokenRing.Log.tLogQueueItem oTokenRingLogQueueItem;
    teFileType eFileType = teFileType.NORMAL;

    try
    {
        for (bool bDone = false; !bDone;)
        {
            //***this is where the missing dequeue is:
            if(oLogQueue.TryDequeue(out QueueElment))
            {
                Write(QueueElment.utcTimeStamp, QueueElment.Data, QueueElment.eFileType, QueueElment.eShowfileOption);
            }

            //array of queues is populated by the calls:
            for (int i = 0; i < this.iConcurrentQueueArraySize; i++)
            {
                if (oLogQueues[i].TryDequeue(out QueueElment))
                {
                    Write(QueueElment.utcTimeStamp, QueueElment.Data, QueueElment.eFileType, QueueElment.eShowfileOption);
                }
            }
            //token ring queue:
            if (rTokenRingLogQueue.TryDequeue(out oTokenRingLogQueueItem))
            {
                if (oTokenRingLogQueueItem.eDestinationFileType == TokenRing.Log.teDestinationFileType.NORMAL)
                    eFileType = teFileType.NORMAL;
                else
                    eFileType = teFileType.BOTH;
                        
                string sArrow="";
                switch(oTokenRingLogQueueItem.eDirection){
                    case TokenRing.Log.teDirection.Rx: sArrow = " -> "; break;
                    case TokenRing.Log.teDirection.Tx: sArrow = " <- "; break;
                }

                Write(
                    oTokenRingLogQueueItem.utcStamp,
                    "Token Ring" + sArrow + oTokenRingLogQueueItem.eDirection.ToString() + " " + oTokenRingLogQueueItem.Text, 
                    eFileType, 
                    teShowfileOption.WRITE_TO_IT);
            }

            //prevents thread from monolopizing CPU time:
            Thread.Sleep(1);
        }
    }
    catch (ThreadAbortException Ex)
    {
        //do nothing; this exception is sometimes thrown when the thread is aborted
    }
    catch (Exception Ex)
    {
        Write(DateTime.UtcNow, "Unanticipated Call::Logging ThreadRoutine #" + Ex.Message, Log.teFileType.EXCEPTION, teShowfileOption.WRITE_TO_IT);
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you know it has the right `ConcurrentQueue` object, maybe it has a reference to the wrong one Please [edit] and show code

Comment: Code is posted.
Thanks, Dave

Comment: Isn't that `bDone` loop going to execute just once? What is it there for anyway? The `TryDequeue` you complain about appears to then be executed just once

Comment: The bDone is false throughout the program's runtime. It only asserts when the program is ending. So the thread routine is always executing. Each time through, it processes one item from each queue. It's done that way so that no queue gets neglected because of a busier queue.

Comment: So how are you breaking out of the loop, TheadAbort? `bDone` is a local variable and is never getting set.

Comment: I had to check that one, because for my other threads, I usually provide access to the bDone from OnStop(). But you're correct with this one. OnStop() calls
   public void AbortThread() {oThread.Abort();}

Comment: The problem has been solved. The cause was banal, and it was self-inflicted: To code a new class instantiation, I copied and modified an existing code block. But in doing so, I accidentally copied more than I meant to, inadvertently instantiating the class that creates the concurrent queues twice.

Comment: Thank you for your interest and help Charlieface.